# sqlite android create unique column that no need to check availability when have to store

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I developing news app that store all of news in sqlite database.
It will be a big database during time.
When i get data from API, check database to have every news and if doesn't exist store them to it. it takes 3-10 sec on every time when app run by user ( will take more during days ).
Is there anyway to store my data to database in an asynctask that doesn't freeze my app ? or another efficient way ?
every news has unique id. can i change my id column to unique that i don't have to check every time and store directly to database and database don't save it when it's available ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayAll.length(); i++)
   if (!db.isNewsExist(news.getNews_id()))
      db.addNews(news);

public boolean isNewsExist(String news_id) {
    boolean exist;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query("news", COLUMNS_NEWS, " news_id = ?",
                    new String[]{news_id}, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit

    if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        return false;
    }
    exist = cursor.getString(1) != null;
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return exist;
}
```

Comment: This is a [FAQ](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes-  just put the update code in the doInBackground of an AsyncTask.  SQLite can handle being called from multiple threads.  As for improvements-  don't query and then add.  Just try to insert-  if the column has a unique constraint that's violated it will throw an exception you can catch and ignore.

Comment: OR use `REPLACE INTO` instead of `INSERT INTO`. This will INSERT if the row doesn't exist or UPDATE, if it does.

Comment: Or use an insert with ON CONFLICT IGNORE and it should silently ignore failures. Lots of ways to do it, depending on the exact results you want